# $facebook->getUser(); returning 0 and throwing OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Before i state my problem i must say that i have visited all these **[SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034813/facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-i)** , **[SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801406/oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about)** , **[SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574992/facebook-app-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-que)** , **[SO 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525731/facebook-fatal-error-uncaught-oauthexception-an-active-access-token-must-be-u)** links and many others and none of them solving my query

with facebook-php-sdk i am trying to login a user. **on first few occasions it was working perfectly fine (2 to 3 days ago.)**. **Today when i started again working with my project its not working any more**.whenever i am trying to login a user  `$facebook->getUser();  throwing Fatal error: Uncaught  OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` i have also noted that **`getuser()` is also returning 0`** though few days back it was working fine.

MY CODE :: **`0auth_provided_by_facebook.php`**

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dist/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$config = array(
   'appId' => '***********',
   'secret' => '*********',
   'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
'cookie'    => true,
'oauth'     => true
 );

 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 if($user_id) {
   try {

      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
   scope'=>'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,publish_stream,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php'
    ));
    echo "EXCEPTION at place 1";
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  //$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,publish_stream,basic_info', 
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php'
    ));
  echo "Exception at place 2";

}
```

It is always throwing the error mentioned above and and printing **Exception at place 2**. which means `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();if($user_id)` returnin false...

---

**EDIT :**

---

as mentioned in the now i have used `getAccessToken` and `setAccessToken` after `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();`

now my code

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dist/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$config = array(
'appId' => '234360450080751',
'secret' => '38189c40cec699c7c0deee2377a2c0a2',
'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
'cookie'    => true,
'oauth'     => true
 );

 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
 $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
 //....REST ARE SAME
```

How to solve it these two problem ??? what is the reason ??

---

i am giving more details it may help you to answer my query.

**my fb app settings :**

1. **APP DOMAIN :** kept it blank according to the comments
2. **SITE URL :** `http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php`
3. **Native or desktop app?** Disabled (i tried by enabling but no help)
4. **Deauthorize Callback URL :** `http://localhost:80/dist/`
5. **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** `http://localhost/dist/include/0auth_provided_by_facebook.php`
6. **Stream post URL security :** ENABLED
7. **Normalize all publish scopes to 'publish_actions :'** Enabled

Comment: what is the domain name specified in the setting page for your app in facebook ? if its something as localhost.. then remove it and save the settings and try again.

Comment: yes it is localhost... if i need to replace it as you said i will replace it with what??

Comment: i had **`localhost.com`** as app domain ... removed it but still not working

Comment: hmm so login works but after it comes back to the page it shows error ? make sure that if you have some redirect url specified on app setting you should use the same in redirect_uri in the login param.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty those are all same .. there must be some other problem i think

Comment: your login code is in the same page as u mentioned? or its a different page and u are re-directing to the above page ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty ...  after user clicks on `<a>login using facebook</a>` my index.php redirects the control to this page after performing success full login facebook returns to this page and from here i exit() and go to home page ... that is the functionality

Comment: ah i see so the issue is not getUser() its the $facebook->api('/me','GET'); which is throwing the error. You can fix it by 
- use iduser in instead of /me as $facebook->api('/$user_id ','GET');
- OR use $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token); and then call api('/me').. this should fix it.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty .... :( :( ...sorry none solved it...is there really any way???..what is the problem..tring to solve it for more than 4 hours..no result –

Comment: same problem here, I've been struggling with Facebook oAuth via PHP SDK since yesterday. No way to get the SDK getUser() to answer anything else than 0. All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: There are few reasons which could lead to return iduser as 0 and they are 
- $_REQUEST method is not working and the lib is not able to get the data
- some sort of settings which is not working well with the app
- cookie is not set up properly using nested folders

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with this same error being thrown. I also looked everywhere for a solution, none of which seemed to solve my particular problem.

Finally, I read Abhik Chakraborty's comment and realized that my OAuth redirect URI wasn't set within my FB App's settings. The user was authenticated but the URI didn't match when the user's info was sent back to my site, which resulted in getUser returning 0.

[image: Find this under Settings > Advanced]

**Here's the catch:** this fix didn't work while I was using localhost, even though it was setup the same as my server. I'll update my answer if I get it working with localhost.